# Css font not changing correctly or aligning to the center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the font-family of my tab and align the text to the center using "font-family" and "text-align" but it isn't working. Here is my code and the image. As you can see the font is not Roboto and the text "Chat" is not aligned properly.

```
<style>
  div#olark_tab{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom:50%;
    z-index:5000;

  }

  #olark_tab div{
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: -59px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  #olark_tab a{
    /*Edit these to change the look of your tab*/
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    color: #1EAFE6;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    border-top-right-radius:9px;
    border-top-left-radius:9px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0;
  }

  #olark_tab a:hover{
    background-color: white;

  }
</style>
    <div id="olark_tab">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="olark('api.box.expand')">
            <img src="icon-chat.svg">
              Chat
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the font, the `font-family` declaration works if you try an already-included font, like Arial or Times New Roman. I don't believe Roboto is a default font that you can just include.  Have you imported it from somewhere like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)?

For the text centering: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "not aligned properly," but it is centered in your example.  Both the "Chat" text and the SVG icon are part of the centered element (the `<a>` tag), so it's those two elements together being centered within the box.  (The same distance extends from the "t" to the top and from the edge of the speech bubble to the bottom.)  Depending on how you actually want it to be aligned, you may need to target the text or image and align them individually.

Comment: by centered I mean within the tab. It's touching the bottom of the tab and not in the center. As in its touching the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - so the issue then is that `text-align` aligns elements on the horizontal axis.  Since your `div` has been rotated 90 degrees, `text-align` is still operating on what it "thinks" is the horizontal axis, but is actually the vertical axis visually.  

The easiest way to fix this will likely be using flexbox.  Try adding the following three rules to `#olark_tab a`: 

`display: flex;`
`align-items: center;`
`justify-content: center;`

You won't need the `text-align: center` rule anymore as `justify-content: center` will be doing that instead.

Comment: thanks for the response. After adding that three rules the icon and text shift down towards the bottom of the tab and not centered. Just to clarify again, I'm wanted for the icon and text to be centered all the way around the tab, so right, left, up and down.

Comment: Is `display: block` still included in the list of style rules?  If so, it may be overwriting `display: flex`.  There should be only one `display` rule set to flex.  And if by "centered all the way around" do you mean having the same space on each side? Check this Fiddle - is this more what you want to do? [https://jsfiddle.net/apLftmq8/](https://jsfiddle.net/apLftmq8/)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: you were right, the block was overriding flex

Comment: Great, glad that's working.  If you still need help getting the spacing right, I've updated the Fiddle to show how to do that.  Only look at the CSS box and see the areas I've commented on.  I would recommend specifically removing any `width` or `height` rule and adding `padding` instead, which will give you a uniform space around your text.  This also shows the Roboto font import rule at the top.  [https://jsfiddle.net/6tb52f1a/](https://jsfiddle.net/6tb52f1a/)

Answer (score 0):

The Roboto font is not supported by css and is only available through google. I have added the code to get the font from google and display it in on the tab.

HTML

```
<style>
  div#olark_tab{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom:50%;
    z-index:5000;

  }

  #olark_tab div{
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: -59px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  #olark_tab a{
    /*Edit these to change the look of your tab*/
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    color: #1EAFE6;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    border-top-right-radius:9px;
    border-top-left-radius:9px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0;
  }

  #olark_tab a:hover{
    background-color: white;

  }
</style>
    <div id="olark_tab">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="olark('api.box.expand')">
            <img src="icon-chat.svg">
              Chat
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your image smaller

```css
div#olark_tab {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 5000;
}

#olark_tab div {
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: -59px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
/* changes */
#olark_tab img{
  width: 50%;/* or :75%; make it the much you want */
}
/* changes */
#olark_tab a {
  /*Edit these to change the look of your tab*/
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  color: #1EAFE6;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  border-top-right-radius: 9px;
  border-top-left-radius: 9px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-top-width: 0;
}

#olark_tab a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="olark_tab">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="olark('api.box.expand')">
      <img src="icon-chat.svg"> Chat
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding that did not work, the text is still stuck to the bottom and not in the middle

Comment: man the problem was in your image, if you change the size it will be fine